# Amending mounted() hook of the extended Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

The system I'm building is based on Nuxt.
I've created some global component by using plugins technique where other component from 3-rd party npm package is imported and extended because I don't want to modificate original component.
Here is a simplified source code of the latter:

```
// simplified version of the component from 3-rd party npm package
<script>
  import LibObj from 'someJSLib'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        dataField: null,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      let that = this
      let initFunc = function (initParam) {

        let actionParam = function (initParam) {
          /* some local generic js code consuming initParam and producing value*/
          return value
        }

        let actionFunc = function (actionParam) {
          actionObj = new LibObj()
          actionObj.listen('event', function(){})
          actionObj.init()
          that.dataField = actionObj // this object reference is "exported" to vue component's data field
        };
        // that.actionFunc = actionFunc // this line of code is absent but I would like have it here


        let condition = function () {/* some local generic js code */}
        if (condition) {
          actionFunc(condition.id);
        }

        /* some more of local generic js code */

      };

      initFunc(cssSelectorString);

    },
  }
</script>
```

And here is what I've tried so far:

```
// simplified version of the file where I register and extend the component above^
// no the logic doing any valuable stuff but rather demonstration of the framework of intentions
import Vue from "vue";
import ExternalComponent from 'ExternalNPMPackage';

Vue.component("ExtendedComponent", {
  extends: ExternalComponent,
  methods: {
    myMethod: function() {
      /* some logic somehow interacting with the scopes of the functions declared in the ExternalComponent */
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    console.log("created() in extended component");
    // this function is called before the code in the mounted() hook of ExternalComponent
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log("mounted() in extended component");
    // this function is called after the code in the mounted() hook of ExternalComponent
  },
});
```

The problem is that all the logic of the original component realised in the "mounted" hook.
In my own component I really feel a lack of reference of `actionFunc` as a component's data field. I would just add `that.actionFunc = actionFunc` for that purpose.
I've already attempted expanding "mounted" hook and adding some logic to kind of "intercept" process of assignments but with no luck of getting access to the scopes of any functions defined there.

What else steps could I make to implement such an injection of code avoiding dumb copying all the code to my own component?

Comment: You can move `actionFunc` to the `methods` object, then you do no need to assign it. And within your initFunc you can simply call `this.actionFunc()` instead. It is generally not a good idea to stash all your functions in your `mounted()` lifecycle hook. Instead, you create methods that are invoked by the hook instead.

Comment: @Terry Yeah, I know. `methods: {}` it is how vue components are meant to be used. But the code I put above is not my own one. It is **from 3-rd party component** which I'm importing and trying somehow to integrate to my component(and not by overwriting the source).Edited the original post to clarify a little bit^

Comment: Then it sounds like bad component design by the 3rd party provider... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ the functions defined in the mounted hook is not accessible by consuming components, so there's really nothing much you could do, unless (1) you manually modify the 3rd party files yourself, or (2) create a PR on that project (if present) to propose improvements to the component's API